# MySQL: Group users by cars owned

Tags: mysql

I'll be honest, MySQL is really not my forte, but I'm learning and knowledge is what I'm seeking here :) I am trying to figure out how to churn out a combined grouped data which eventually will be output as nested JSON (JSON part not necessary for now). So..

I've got a table of people...

```
user_info:
-----------
id | name
---+-------
 1 | Joh
 2 | Doe
 3 | Bob
```

along with a table of cars...

```
cars:
-----------
id | cars
---+-------
 1 | Toyota
 2 | Honda
 3 | Mazda
```

and a table that groups them, with their registration numbers...

```
user_cars:    
-----------------------------
id | user_id | car_id | reg
---+---------+--------+------
 1 |       1 |      2 | AB1
 2 |       2 |      3 | BC2
 3 |       3 |      1 | CB2
 4 |       3 |      1 | AC3
```

A person can have more than one car and I would like to generate a grouped table as such:

```
---------------
user  |  car1
      |  car2
------+--------
user  |  car1
      |  car2
------+--------
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT
    user_info.id,
    user_info.name,
    user_cars.car_id,
    user_cars.reg
FROM
    user_info
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_cars ON user_cars.user_id = user_info.id;
```

But that's not really what I want. It gives me duplicate of names which doesn't help. Any enlightenment would be very much appreciated.
I'm pretty sure this might have been asked on SO, and I'm using the wrong keywords to search most probably. Like I mentioned, knowledge is what I seek. If it's a redirect to another existing post, that would be very much appreciated too.

Comment: What table is Reg in?

Comment: You're confusing issues of data retrieval and data display. This is a display problem, and should be solved in your application code (php and/or js)

Comment: @Matt Reg is in user_cars table..

Comment: @Strawberry is it not possible to output from MySQL itself in that way?

Comment: All things are possible.

Comment: The reason why you're struggling to find something is as strawberry points out.  this problem is usually handled at a different level of the OSI model (Physical, data, network, transport, session, presentation, application)   Mixing those levels can cause problems on ease of maintenance long term.. But if you must... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680459/hide-duplicate-results-in-mysql-query/42680823#42680823  or, if you want a comma separated list of the cars and one record, you could use `group_concat()`

Comment: @xQbert Thanks a lot! That's helpful. I have a very specific use case of this. That was exactly what I needed. ^_^