# how to correspond row mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

i have 2 results from 2 queries,

this is queries 1

```
(SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT om.createdby) AS pul_org,
            SUM(om.quantity) AS order_pul_kg,
            COUNT(om.id) AS order_pul_x
    FROM
        order_match om
    Inner JOIN (SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00')) clients ON om.createdby = clients.createdby
    WHERE
        order_status_id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8));
```

the results of queries 1 was like this  (this is just dummy results)

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| pul_org | order_pul_kg | order_pul_x |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|       6 |         2345 |         428 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

this is queries 2

```
(SELECT 
        COALESCE(customer_regency, 'total') AS `Kabupaten/Kota_PUL`,
            SUM(quantity) AS `Qty_PUL(kg)`,
            ROUND(SUM(quantity) / ANY_VALUE(totalsum) * 100, 1) AS `Qty_PUL(%)`,
            COUNT(order_match.id) AS `Jumlah Order_PUL`,
            ROUND(COUNT(order_match.id) / ANY_VALUE(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Jumlah Order_PUL(%)`
    FROM
        order_match
    INNER JOIN air_way_bills ON order_match.code_order = air_way_bills.code_order
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00')) clients ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
    JOIN (SELECT 
        SUM(quantity) totalsum, COUNT(order_match.id) totalcount
    FROM
        order_match
    INNER JOIN ((SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00'))) clients ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
    WHERE
        order_status_Id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
            AND createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00') totals
    WHERE
        order_status_Id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
        and order_match.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY customer_regency WITH ROLLUP) AS PULRegency;
```

the results of queries 2 was just like this (this is just dummy results)

```
+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| kabupaten/kota | qty_PUL (kg) | Qty_PUL(%) | jumlah_order_PUL  | jumlah_order_pul(%) |
+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| kota a         |           20 |         20 |                 1 |                  20 |
| kota b         |           40 |         40 |                 2 |                  40 |
| kota c         |           40 |         40 |                 2 |                  40 |
| total          |          100 |        100 |                 4 |                 100 |
+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

so i want to combine this results into 1 tables
this is expected results

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| pul_org | order_pul_kg | order_pul_x | kabupaten/kota | qty_PUL (kg) | Qty_PUL(%) | jumlah_order_PUL  | jumlah_order_pul(%) |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|       6 |      2345.31 |         428 | kota a         |           20 |         20 |                 1 |                  20 |
|         |              |             | kota b         |           40 |         40 |                 2 |                  40 |
|         |              |             | kota c         |           40 |         40 |                 2 |                  40 |
|         |              |             | total          |          100 |        100 |                 4 |                 100 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

based on expected results, i make this queries

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT om.createdby) AS pul_org,
            SUM(om.quantity) AS order_pul_kg,
            COUNT(om.id) AS order_pul_x
    FROM
        order_match om
    Inner JOIN (SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00')) clients ON om.createdby = clients.createdby
    WHERE
        order_status_id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)) AS PULOrder
        cross JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COALESCE(customer_regency, 'total') AS `Kabupaten/Kota_PUL`,
            SUM(quantity) AS `Qty_PUL(kg)`,
            ROUND(SUM(quantity) / ANY_VALUE(totalsum) * 100, 1) AS `Qty_PUL(%)`,
            COUNT(order_match.id) AS `Jumlah Order_PUL`,
            ROUND(COUNT(order_match.id) / ANY_VALUE(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Jumlah Order_PUL(%)`
    FROM
        order_match
    INNER JOIN air_way_bills ON order_match.code_order = air_way_bills.code_order
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00')) clients ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
    JOIN (SELECT 
        SUM(quantity) totalsum, COUNT(order_match.id) totalcount
    FROM
        order_match
    INNER JOIN ((SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00'))) clients ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
    WHERE
        order_status_Id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
            AND createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00') totals
    WHERE
        order_status_Id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
        and order_match.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY customer_regency WITH ROLLUP) AS PULRegency;
```

but why the results was like this

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| pul_org | order_pul_kg | order_pul_x | kabupaten/kota | qty_PUL (kg) | Qty_PUL(%) | jumlah_order_PUL  | jumlah_order_pul(%) |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|       6 |      2345.31 |         428 | kota a         |           20 |         20 |                 1 |                  20 |
|       6 |      2345.31 |         428 | kota b         |           40 |         40 |                 2 |                  40 |
|       6 |      2345.31 |         428 | kota c         |           40 |         40 |                 2 |                  40 |
|       6 |      2345.31 |         428 | total          |          100 |        100 |                 4 |                 100 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------------
```

this is not what i want because the row not same with my expected results

Comment: This requirement is mainly presentation, and might best be handled in your application layer (e.g. PHP), where you actually process the result set.

Comment: i process this in mysql workbench 5.7

Comment: Does the only problem is in non-empty column values for `pul_org | order_pul_kg | order_pul_x` columns in all rows except first one in the output?

Comment: sorry i mean i process this with mysql 5.7, and yes, the problem is that, the coloumn should be only 1 row.

Comment: the coloumn is should be only 1 row for pul_org | order_pul_kg | order_pul_x

Comment: There is no any sorting in the output (ORDER BY in outer query) which allows to determine what row is "first". You MUST add it, and this sorting expression MUST provide rows uniqueness. But I recommend you to eliminate (do not output) the values for all another rows on the client side. Of course the asterisk in `SELECT *` in outer query will be replaced with separate columns names / expressions.

Comment: It is possible to do this, for a relatively easy way see e.g. [Hide duplicate results in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42680459). The "f" in that answer is your "PULRegency", add the rest accordingly. But as the answer there, all comments there and all comments here tell you: it is much better to do this in the client that displays the data (as it has only to do with data representation), not in sql. Also note that this method will not work anymore in MySQL 9 (at least according to the current roadmap).

Comment: based on your explanation, i think between queries 1 and queries 2 are not related, so there's no "first" row, because there's no related between 2 queries, then the results have to be based on the row itself (which queries 1 should be 1 row, and queries 2 more than 1 row) @Akina

Comment: i think the link you shared its only when between tables (or more) are having related, instead in my case, this 2 tables just only 1 similarity which is the parameter (the date), based on your explanation, it is better to do this on not mysql? @Solarflare

Comment: or can you just posted the answers so i can modify it? @Solarflare

Comment: *based on your explanation, i think .. so there's no "first" row* You think wrongly. It is nevertheless - in output, where physical ordering appears. And if you want to solve your task then you must make this ordering definite and deterministic.

Comment: can you give me advice what's the best i can do to solved this problem?  @Akina

Comment: The linked answer does not rely on having 2 tables. `(SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY brand, description, prodcode) f` represents whatever result you have that has values in all rows (e.g. what you would usually send to the client). Just put your query there. Then adjust the other outer parts (e.g. the column names - maybe start with `pul_org` until it works, add the other 2 columns later). Apart from column names, I would just literally have to copy the other answer 1:1 (including the "do not do it"-disclaimer), so I won't post this as an answer (but feel free to do it to mark this as solved).

Comment: You may, for example, wrap your 2nd query into outer query which enumerates the rows in its output by some order (for example, use `ORDER BY customer_regency = 'total', customer_regency`). Then use CASE in the output of the final query, print 3 columns in question only for a row where this row number is 1 and empty string `''` otherwise.

Comment: tbh i dont understand because my english was so bad and im new on mysql, so can you just give a clue, maybe more clue if you guys didnt post the answer?

Comment: Formatting is an application task.  It is quite messy to simulate this in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the best solution would be using client side software but  you could try this query. It worked for me with an easier query but still with a cross join

You will have one more output field (OneIncrementingField). At the end of the script the @a initialisation

```
SELECT
    @a:=@a+1 OneIncrementingField ,
    if(@a=1,pul_org ,'') pul_org,
    if(@a=1,order_pul_kg ,'')  order_pul_kg,
    if(@a=1,order_pul_x ,'') order_pul_x,
    PULRegency.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT om.createdby) AS pul_org,
            SUM(om.quantity) AS order_pul_kg,
            COUNT(om.id) AS order_pul_x
    FROM
        order_match om
    Inner JOIN (SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00')) clients ON om.createdby = clients.createdby
    WHERE
        order_status_id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)) AS PULOrder
        cross JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COALESCE(customer_regency, 'total') AS `Kabupaten/Kota_PUL`,
            SUM(quantity) AS `Qty_PUL(kg)`,
            ROUND(SUM(quantity) / ANY_VALUE(totalsum) * 100, 1) AS `Qty_PUL(%)`,
            COUNT(order_match.id) AS `Jumlah Order_PUL`,
            ROUND(COUNT(order_match.id) / ANY_VALUE(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Jumlah Order_PUL(%)`
    FROM
        order_match
    INNER JOIN air_way_bills ON order_match.code_order = air_way_bills.code_order
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00')) clients ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
    JOIN (SELECT 
        SUM(quantity) totalsum, COUNT(order_match.id) totalcount
    FROM
        order_match
    INNER JOIN ((SELECT 
        s1.createdby
    FROM
        order_match s1
    GROUP BY s1.createdby
    HAVING SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt <= '2020-04-30 00:00:00') > 1
        AND SUM(s1.order_status_id != 7
        AND s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00'))) clients ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
    WHERE
        order_status_Id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
            AND createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00') totals
    WHERE
        order_status_Id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
        and order_match.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY customer_regency WITH ROLLUP) AS PULRegency , (select @a:=0) as P;
```

Comment: this is the output that i want, let me learning by myself, because in my real case, there's more than 2 sp that i want to combine, thankyou in advance

Comment: hi sir, i add some  cross join but why the results was zeroo? is that any rules about this query?

Comment: there's no rule. it depends on where you put the incrementing instruction on the @a variable

Answer (score -1):

The output of the cross-join you are getting is correct based on the input you have shared. That is what cross-join does; it maps all rows from one table to each and every row of other table.

Now if you want to group the rows further, you can do a groupby `pul_org`. Your query should look something like below:

```
select pul_org, group_concat(kabupaten/kota)
from (
  <your big cross join query>
)
group by pul_org;
```

Additionally cross-joins are very resource-intensive in themselves if you have large amt of data; and doing a group by on top of it will make your query performance go worse.

Comment: this is absolutely wrong, i've tried and the output was like not what i expected

Comment: @FachryDzaky I hope you saw the first line of my answer. The result structure you are getting is what you will get from mysql. SQL is not a language to format your output. That should be and can be easily done in application layer as others have suggested in above comments.