# MySql Select Query hide duplicate values in column

Tags: mysql

In the image, I have two records that have the same payment ID, and I sum everything related to that payment ID but when I try to show it separate items I come across a problem when someone pays the amount that they pay will be stored and I don't know how to hide the duplicates, sorry for little info, but I wanna make paid amount column to show that 600 once and for the next row be empty is that possible by query or its fixed in visual studio

total       paid amount

300          600

300                    //this cell be empty
Query:

```
 select `payment`.`id_payment` as `Payment ID`,
       `payment`.`doctor_id` as `Doctor ID`,
       `patient_information`.`id_user` as `Code`,
       CONCAT (`patient_information`.`firstname`,
       ' ', `patient_information`.`middlename`,
       ' ',
       `patient_information`.`lastname`) as `Customer`,
       `payment`.`date` as `Date`,
       `bills`.`name` as `Tretment`,
      (COALESCE(SUM(`items`.`sell_price`),0)+sum(`bills`.`price`)) as `Total`,
       `payment`.`amount` as `Paid amount`,
      `payment`.`discount`,
       `payment`.`status` as `Status`,
       COALESCE(sum(items.price),0) as `R.M`,
       (COALESCE(sum(items.sell_price),0)+`bills`.`price`) - sum(items.price)  AS `G.P`
  from (((((`payment` `payment`
  inner join `patient_information`
       `patient_information`
       on (`patient_information`.`id_user` = `payment`.`paitent_id`))
  inner join `paymen_information`
       `paymen_information`
       on (`paymen_information`.`id_payment` = `payment`.`id_payment`))
  inner join `bills` `bills`
       on (`bills`.`id_bill` = `paymen_information`.`id_bill`))
  inner join `bill_information` `bill_information`
       on (`bill_information`.`bills_id` = `bills`.`id_bill`))
  inner join `items` `items`
       on (`items`.`id_item` = `bill_information`.`item_id`))
         WHERE payment.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
         GROUP by `payment`.`id_payment`,`bills`.`id_bill`,`paymen_information`.`id`
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: Please don't force people here to debug screenshots. Post a [mcve] of your data, current code and desired result as text here so people here don't have to re-type your data just to answer your question.

Comment: At a minimum, post your current query

Comment: @Kevin i added the Query

Comment: @Kevin i wanna make paid amount column to show that 600 once and for the next row be empty is that possible by query or its fixed in visual studio

Comment: you can just add DISTINCT on the Payment ID column as a temporary solution but there should not be duplicate payments with one payment id in your database.

Comment: It isn't duplicate but every payment has some items assign to it, when I wanna show them  i have duplicate data in paid amount cell, i wanna eliminate it, i found this but this will eliminate everything :( hope you get me take a look at this @AliMomeni https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680459/hide-duplicate-results-in-mysql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve, but if Payment ID is your primary key it should be set as Unique to avoid this kind of situations. For cleaning duplicates you can run a DELETE JOIN query like in the next link:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/